# Rename files and directories with a special characters on solaris machines

Tags: find, solaris, perl, ksh, exec

The target of the following code ( commands ) is to rename files/directories and also support files/directories with a special characters as "@" or "." etc

those commands are run fine on Linux without any problems ,

```
 export NAME_THAT_WE_WANT_TO_CHANGE='.com'
 export NEW_NAME='@google'
 find /tmp -name '*.com*' -print0 | xargs -0  ./rename.pl   's/\Q$ENV{NAME_THAT_WE_WANT_TO_CHANGE}\E/$1$ENV{NEW_NAME}$2/'
```

for example the files

```
/tmp/star.com 
/tmp/public.com
```

will replaced after running the below command to

```
/tmp/star@google 
/tmp/public@google
```

so now I am tring  to covert the find syntax to support Solaris machines ( Solaris 10 )

and this what I write for Solaris:

```
  export NAME_THAT_WE_WANT_TO_CHANGE='.com'
  export NEW_NAME='@google'

  find /tmp -name '*.com*' -exec ./rename.pl  {} + 's/\Q$ENV{NAME_THAT_WE_WANT_TO_CHANGE}\E/$1$ENV{NEW_NAME}$2/'
```

but when I run the find line ... ( I get the following errors )

```
find: paths must precede expression
Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [path...] [expression]
```

please advice what I need to fix in my syntax in order to support solaris machines ?

- About the rename.pl script I took it from                                                         (             http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/perl/cookbook/ch09_10.htm )

  ```
   more /tmp/rename.pl
   #!/usr/bin/perl
   #
   # rename script examples from lwall:
   #       rename 's/\.orig$//' *.orig
   #       rename 'y/A-Z/a-z/ unless /^Make/' *
   #       rename '$_ .= ".bad"' *.f
   #       rename 'print "$_: "; s/foo/bar/ if <stdin> =~ /^y/i' *

   $op = shift;
   for (@ARGV) {
   $was = $_;
   eval $op;
   die $@ if $@;
   rename($was,$_) unless $was eq $_;
   }
  ```

Comment: Install and use the GNU utilities. That way you get to use the same command line as in Linux, and avoid pitfalls like names with spaces and other junk in them. In my experience, Solaris utilities are archaic or just too POSIXly correct for their own good.

Comment: I can't to install because some internal issues , so the single solution is fit the "find" syntax for solaris ...

Comment: @vonbrand - it is possible to migrate my question to starckoverflow ?

Comment: I believe it is fine here, it is a Unix/Linux problem after all.

Comment: yes But after one hour I not get any answer?

Comment: There have been questions with no answers for _months_... patience, little grasshopper.

Comment: I see you are confortable with Perl, perhaps [`File::Find`](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Find.html) (also documentation for [newbies](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=217166)) is your best bet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `{} \;` and `{} +` parameters only work at the *end* of the command, the way `xargs` works.

This is not a Solaris problem.

The examples within `rename.pl` clearly show the filenames go on the end of the command.

Try:

```
find /tmp -name '*.com*' -exec ./rename.pl  \
  's/\Q$ENV{NAME_THAT_WE_WANT_TO_CHANGE}\E/$1$ENV{NEW_NAME}$2/' {} +
```

"@" and "." do not count a special characters in this context. You need `find -print0` and `xargs -0` to robustly handle all filenames (e.g. with embedded newlines in the name).
You can also use the same `find ...| xargs ...` method on Solaris, though without the "0" options, unless you install the GNU findutils and use `gfind` and `gxargs` as also suggested by @vonbrand.

Comment: what do you mean ""@" and "." do not count a special characters in this context" , I tested your solution and it replaced the special characters so I not see any problem here ,

Comment: They are not shell meta-characters (`| & > <` etc), are not white-space, are not control-characters (`^G` etc) -- so they don't strictly need a `-print0` or special handling. It's good practise to quote, escape and use -`print0` where possible, especially with unknown/untrusted filenames.

Comment: ok so I also tested your solution on linux , and your solution fit also for linux so I not need two diff commands , I can use your solution for linux & solaris to replace files/dirs with uniq characters , am I right here ?

Comment: spuratic - did you read my last quastion ?

Comment: I believe it is a good solution for both platforms.